# Alternatives to Google Refine?

Tags: openrefine

Can anyone recommend a tool for cleaning/scrubbing data other than Google Refine?  I don't have any particular reason for not wanting to use Google Refine, I just want to evaluate some alternatives.  Ideally, the tool would be able to operate on millions of records.  I've heard that Google Refine has some issues with large data sets.  I'm just starting to evaluate these products, so I haven't witnessed any issues personally yet.

(Can't add a tag for google-refine)

Editorial Note: Google Refine is now called OpenRefine.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest taking a look at Data Wrangler http://vis.stanford.edu/wrangler/.  It appears to be a web service.